# Inserting text into an XML-file element using xpath

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree, xml.etree

I want to add an element to a specific position of an XML path using XPath and a tag. Since in my original code I have many subnodes, I don't want to use other functions such as *etree.Element* or *tree.SubElement*.

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse('example.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

destination = root.xpath('interprets/interpretNames/interpret[2]/album')[0]
destination.insert(0, 'Thriller')
```

The initial *example.xml* file:

```
<interprets>
    <interpretNames>
        <interpret>
            <name>Queen</name>
            <album></album>
        <interpret>
        <interpret>
            <name>Michael Jackson</name>
            <album></album>
        <interpret>
        <interpret>
            <name>U2</name>
            <album></album>
        <interpret>
    </interpretNames>
</interprets>
```

The *example.xml* file after the element was created and inserted:

```
<interprets>
    <interpretNames>
        <interpret>
            <name>Queen</name>
            <album></album>
        <interpret>
        <interpret>
            <name>Michael Jackson</name>
            <album>Thriller</album>
        <interpret>
        <interpret>
            <name>U2</name>
            <album></album>
        <interpret>
    </interpretNames>
</interprets>
```

However, when I run my original code, I get an:

```
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

I double-checked to make sure the subpaths at the tag position exist, and they do. What am I missing?

Comment: You should be posting the original code and original XML instead of a working sample

Comment: @Kris What we see here (apart from errors in the XML) is the original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foremost, there is an issue in your `example.xml` file. If you carefully read the error message, you'll see that the closing tags are missing.

Here is the fixed file:

```
<interprets>
    <interpretNames>
        <interpret>
            <name>Queen</name>
            <album></album>
        </interpret>             <!-- HERE -->
        <interpret>
            <name>Michael Jackson</name>
            <album></album>
        </interpret>             <!-- HERE -->
        <interpret>
            <name>U2</name>
            <album></album>
        </interpret>             <!-- HERE -->
    </interpretNames>
</interprets>
```

(`HERE` shows where you used opening tags instead of closing tags)

After fixing the XML file, the next error message tells you that there is an index error in line 6. Here you should remove the dangling `[0]` and the error message will disappear. But you are not done yet, by inspecting `destination` like here

```
print(destination)
destination.insert(0, 'Thriller')
print(destination)
```

you'll see

```
[]
['Thriller']
```

that `destination` *has* changed.

But destination is plain Python `list` object. That's why you cannot modify the tree through it.

So now, after a bit of (re)seach, I'd suggest fixing it this way:

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse('example.xml')
el = tree.find('interpretNames/interpret[2]/album')
el.text = 'Thriller'
tree.write('example-mod.xml')
```

The `text` attribute is already present in: [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.text) for which `lxml`'s `etree` is an extension.

I can understand your wish, it may work by means of xpath. But if it is not possible, maybe you should accept that? One can also wish that one can take a certain commodity from the supermarket without paying, but this wish does not lead far.

Comment: @ Wolf Thank you for your profound answer! That works, however the reason why I explicitly want to use xpath is that I also want to create new nodes with it. I. e. I want to provide a path along with some tags which specify the subpath of the new path and element to create. (without using etree.Element or etree.Subelement) Hence, I think I cannot only use the etree.find() method.

Comment: @ Wolf It would be indeed quite handy if you could provide the argument for xpath() in the same way as for the find() method - namely the path including possible tags.